# Optional Relation fields messing up Prisma Studio

Tags: prisma

I'm creating a notification system in my app, and I created a `Notification` model in Prisma to help handle this. It has two optional relation fields, optional because it can point to either a question or an answer, but not both, and not neither.

```
model Notification {
  id                 Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  for                User      @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  read               Boolean   @default(false)
  question_reference Question? @relation(fields: [questionId], references: [id])
  answer_reference   Answer?   @relation(fields: [answerId], references: [id])

  userId     Int
  questionId Int?
  answerId   Int?
}
```

I'm trying to create a notification in Prisma Studio, but whenever I open it, I get an error. Looking at the logs, it is clear why this error is happening. Prisma Studio is making an invalid query.

```
{
  "modelName": "Notification",
  "operation": "findMany",
  "args": {
    "take": 100,
    "skip": 0,
    "select": {
      "id": true,
      "for": true,
      "read": true,
      "question_reference": true,
      "answer_reference": true,
      "userId": true,
      "questionId": true,
      "answerId": true
    }
  }
}
```

You can see the problem in the `select` statement. The two optional relation fields, which should have been in `include` are present here.

I didn't expect this new error, because I have used Prisma Studio in the past and never received this sort of error with any relation field. I tried upgrading to v4.10 but nothing has changed. I also tried running `prisma migrate dev`, but it returns "no schema change or pending migration was found".

#### Reproduction

1. On prisma studio, create a `Notification` model. This requires a previously created question and user model.
2. Select "Add Record", and fill in the parameters. You should use the already created User and Question records for the foreign key values.
3. You find the error detailed above

Comment: What is the exact error message that you get? Can you share the create query through which I can reproduce this locally?

Comment: There is no exact query that I ran, because it was through Prisma Studio. I edited the question to include reproduction steps. @NurulSundarani